# tried to get an array from a C func in Python3

Tags: python, c, python-3.x

I tried to use ctypes to get an array from a C func in Python3, failed.

The system is macOS Mojave 10.14.5.The version of Python3 is 3.7.3.

Here is C code:

```
#include "stdlib.h"

#include "stdio.h"

int* func(int num){

    int *result = (int *)malloc(num*sizeof(int)), i=num ;
    while (i-->0){
        result[i] = num-i;
        printf("%d:%d\n",i, num-i);
    }
    return result;
}
```

And here is Python3 code:
    from ctypes import *

```
dll = CDLL('./test.so')
func = dll.func
func.argtypes = [c_int]
func.restypes = POINTER(c_int*12)
res = func(12)#Here res is an int
res = cast(res, POINTER(c_int*12)).contents
for i in res:
    print(i)#Segmentation fault: 11
```

I except the result can be converted to a numpy.ndarray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in the attribute `func.restypes`.
It should be called `func.restype` (See the doc [here](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/ctypes.html#ctypes._FuncPtr.restype)).
Changing the attribute removes the segfault for me and correctly prints the array.

This also makes the cast redundant, and you can directly iterate over the contents like so:

```
func = dll.func
func.argtypes = [c_int]
func.restype = POINTER(c_int*12)
res = func(12)
for i in res.contents:
    print(i)
```

Comment: @SovLynE If the answer solved your problem, you can mark it as answered by clicking the tick mark below the voting buttons.